# MPlayer: change sound pitch and speed independently

Tags: audio, signal-processing, mplayer

I have spent some time experimenting with [MPlayer slave mode protocol](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt): in a custom application I have two controls: one for changing pitch and one for changing speed.

This is easy to implement using the *scaletempo* filter and *speed_set* / *speed_mult* commands from the MPlayer API.

There's a problem however if I try to modify pitch and speed independently. To give an example: I would like to be able to slow down the speed by e. g. 20%, while transposing the pitch up two or three semitones.

I've tried to do this with adding two scaletempo filters, but without success:

```
af_add scaletempo=scale=1.0:speed=pitch
speed_mult 1.1224620482959342
af_add scaletempo=scale=0.8:speed=tempo
```

This method changes speed, preserving the original pitch.

Is there any other solution to do this with MPlayer or any other media player?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

interesting question. As far as mplayer goes, [here](https://markplusplus.wordpress.com/2006/10/01/pitch-correct-play-speed-with-mplayer/) is one idea, it looks to be free. [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scaletempo/) may be more what you are after. Of course you could go in a different direction with [this](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/). There's quite a bit of stuff on the net. I hope this helps you get started! CHEERS!

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it with LADSPA. The command line looks like this: mplayer -ao jack -af ladspa=/usr/lib/ladspa/tap_pitch.so:tap_pitch:0:40:-90:0 -speed 0.8 tune.mp3   -  This raises the pitch 40%, while setting speed to 0.8.